# iOS 7 UI elements

Tags: iphone, uikit, ios7, look-and-feel

My understanding of iOS 7 was that when it was running on a given device that older applications (complied for iOS 6) that use standard UIControls (UITableView, UINavigationController, etc) would automagically have the iOS 7 look.

I have an app which utilizes a UITabBarController, UINavigationController, a UITableView and some UIButtons, however none of the controls in my app have the iOS 7 look or feel.

My navigation controllers are not translucent or blurred and my back buttons are not words they are still arrow encapsulated.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your input,
Regards,
John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you app is compiled for iOS SDK version 6, you'll have the iOS6 components on your app, even if your phone is upgraded to iOS7.

To see the new components in your app you'll have to compile it using iOS SDK version 7, fix the warnings/errors you will find to make it work, and submit it.

Comment: Thanks, will mark as answered in 4 minutes when i'm allowed, appreciate the response.